# for loop in selenium webdriver and nodejs doesn't execute asynchronously

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a selenium webdriver script which isn't executed as expected. May be I am not understanding promises and async properly. Below is the code -

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var promise = require('selenium-webdriver').promise;
var By = webdriver.By;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('../config/db');
var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
var path = require('chromedriver').path;
var service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder(path).build();
chrome.setDefaultService(service);
var ScrapperModel = require('../models/scrapper-model');
function test1() {
    var dbObj = new ScrapperModel({ name: 'Tom' });
    dbObj.save(function(err, doc){
        if(err){
            console.log("Error saving object in schema"+err);
        }
    });

    var browser = new webdriver.Builder().usingServer().withCapabilities({ 'browserName': 'chrome' }).build();
    browser.get('https://www.example.com/').then(function () {
        return browser.getTitle();
    }
    ).then(function (title) {
        console.log("Title is" + title);
    }).then(function(){
        return browser.findElement(By.id('orderNumber')).sendKeys('12345');  
    }).then(function(){
        return browser.findElement(By.id('orderEmail')).sendKeys('test@test.com');   
    }).then(function(){
        return browser.findElement(By.id('postalCode')).sendKeys('46204');   
    }).then(function(){
        return browser.findElement(By.name('findorder')).click();  
    }).then(function(){
        return browser.findElements(By.xpath('//*[@class="order-shipment-table"]'));
    }).then(function(elements){
        console.log("****"+elements.length);
        elements.forEach(function(element){
            //console.log("---"+element.getAttribute('class'));
            return browser.findElement(By.id('someid'));
            anotherFunction(browser);
            //console.log("++"+element.getAttribute('class'));
        });     

    }).then(function () {
        console.log("closing");
        return browser.close();
    })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("err" + err);
            return browser.close();
        });
};

function anotherFunction(browser){
consolelog("inside function");
}
module.exports.test1 = test1;
```

Here, the code works fine other than the for loop that I need to use. There are some webelements on the page for which I am using `browser.findElement` and then need to execute over them using a for loop and based on some condition need to call a function in the same file to do some more execution using browser object. If I use forloop, it executes immediately and the code inside only works for the last value i.e. if for loop is supposed to be executed from 1 to 5, it will print 1 to 5 correctly but the script picks only 5 due to asynchronous behavior. I tried using forEach like below but it returns me -
`(node:15420) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (reje
ction id: 1): NoSuchSessionError: no such session`
after executing all the steps and closing the browser. If I reomove this loop, all works fine.

Is there any way where in I can execute these selenium webdriver commands in for loop and for loop waits for the next iteration till the commands are not executed. These commands are returning promises I believe.

If I use forloop like below -

```
.then(function(){
    for (var row = 2; row < count; row++) {
        return driver.findElement(By.id('itemid')).then(function(order){
            console.log("++++"+row);
            return order.findElement(By.xpath('//table/tbody/tr[' + row+ ']/td[2]/span[1]')).getText();
        }).then(function(productName){
            console.log("i am ok .."+productName);
       });          
    }
}).then(function(){
    return driver.close();
})
```

It only executes the driver.findElement command for the last value of row. If I put the first return statement in this for loop (like above), it only executes for row =2 and closes the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is asynchronous inside a synchronous loop:

```
for (var row = 2; row < count; row++) {
        return driver.findElement(By.id('itemid')).then(function(order){
            console.log("++++"+row);
            return order.findElement(By.xpath('//table/tbody/tr[' + row+ ']/td[2]/span[1]')).getText();
        }).then(function(productName){
            console.log("i am ok .."+productName);
       });          
}
```

What actually is happening is that when the loop starts, the value of row = 2. Then you call an asynchronous function `driver.findElement`. The callback goes into the queue and then row value is updated to 3 and the same thing happens.

Now when the callback is fired (when the asynchronous task is done), the value of the row is the last value.

You can keep a separate array of rows, and map the orders to that. Please try Promise.all().

```
const P = require('bluebird');
const _ = require('lodash');
const rows = [2, 3, 4, 5];

const exampleFunction = (rows) => {
    return P.try(() => {
        const promises = _.map(rows, (e) => {
        return driver.findElement(e);
    });

    return P.all(promises);
    }).then((results) => {
        return P.all(_.map(results, (e, index) => {
            return e.findElement(By.xpath('//table/tbody/tr[' + rows[index]+ ']/td[2]/span[1]')
        }));
    });
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use Promise.all() but not really sure how that fits in here. Would it be possible to show with two lines in this reference? Shall I create a new promise and keep the driver statements in it?

Comment: You can keep an array of rows outside and pass it to a function. Check my edit.

Comment: P.try, what is P here?

Comment: P = require('bluebird')

Comment: I get ManagedPromise::606 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"} error

Comment: That is a promise. You have to do a .then()